# Cypress checking disabled input field?

Tags: cypress

So maybe this is a HTML thing and not a Cypress thing, but when I check an a disabled input fields `text` it shows as `''`

However doing the same with `value` ie: `cy.get(`input`).should('have.value', 'Some Text')` works, but not `should('have.text')`

Curious why this is?

Comment: Thank you for your question — I was wondering why my `should('have.text)` did not work; `have.value` did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`have.text` checks for the text within that element.

`<p>This is the text within a paragraph element</p>`

An input's value is not displayed in the DOM which is why `have.text` gives a value of `''`.

`have.value` checks for the value of the input.